# How can I get the first visible item/index from a ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

How can I get the first `Item`/`index` that is visible in a `ListView`? I looked inside the documentation and also searched a lot on the Internet but couldn't find anything. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably exploit `highlightRangeMode` or the `contentY` properties. Anyhow, why do you want to know that? What's the specific  result you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to hold the list view at the current position even if the model is changed. Now, if my model is changed the list jumps at the beginning.

Comment: Oh, the problem from the other question. Maybe `highlightRangeMode` could be of help.

Comment: Ok, take a look at this [example](http://pastebin.com/PVsUKyfy). The possible drawback of this approach is that the list moves strinctly within the highlight range which means that, when at the end, only the last `Item` is visible at the top of the list. See if the approach fits with your use case.

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like that:

```
ListView {
        id: contacts
        model: UsersModel

        onContentYChanged: {
            var CurrentIndexAtTop = indexAt(1, contentY)
            var CurrentPropFromModel = UsersModel.get(CurrentIndexAtTop).Name
        }
}
```

if indexAt return -1 means not found, check this if need!
contentY - it is a property of ListView, that return current position top Y-coord of ViewList window on flickable grid ListView.

see documentation for more details http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#indexAt-method

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but for others seeking help:

You can use the member method `myView.indexAt(QPoint(0,0))` to find the first index.

I've also made a snippet to find all visible indexes in a view if you need that too:
https://gist.github.com/iSplasher/8ebc42eaf9ea206b19bd

Comment: good to know, but it won't necessarily work with spacing > 0 and when scroll is per pixel and not per item

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected index when it changes.
Once the model changes and the index becomes -1, you can use `positionViewAtIndex` to restore the right position.

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#positionViewAtIndex-method) the documentation of the method.

Otherwise, you can do the same relying on the `add` and `remove` method.
Obviously, it works as far as the index of the selected item changes.
You can also get the index of the visible item by means of the `indexAt` method, but I've never used it before, even though it looks easy to use.

So, you have several methods to get the index of the visible item and you can reset the view by means of the method above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Based on iSplasher's answer, the following works when QListView has spacing and/or has scroll by pixel:

```
sp = view.spacing()
first = max(view.indexAt(QPoint(sp, 0)), view.indexAt(QPoint(sp, sp * 2)))
```